# Has anyone formalized what a natural undecidable statement is?

Tags: logic, reference-request

It is a primary research objective of some logicians to find examples of natural undecidable statements in Peano Arithmetic. This may in fact turn out to be impossible. The only way to know would be to give a formal, unambiguous definition of natural undecidable statement, at least one that most closely matches our intuitive definition. Has there been a definition of it in the math literature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't believe anyone in the field has done this - or seriously thinks it can be done.

There is certainly a lot of discussion about what constitutes a natural principle, a lot of which can be found by looking through Harvey Friedman's postings at the foundations of mathematics mailing list and the responses they generate (see [here](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/foundational-adventures/fom-email-list/)). However, this of course falls short of proposing a precise *definition* of naturality, or even a claim that such should exist. Even the question of what *Diophantine equations* count as "natural" is totally opaque. (And this is relevant since per [the (internalized) MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set) we can whip up a Diophantine equation the solvability of which is independent of $\mathsf{PA}$.)